# With AutoMapper, how can you read a settings file inside a profile if your source object is an IQueryable?

Tags: c#, .net-core, asp.net-web-api, automapper

I am using AutoMapper in a .Net Core 3.1 project.

Inside one of the mapping profiles, for a member that exists only in the destination object, I need to set the value according to a value from the settings file (the [appsettings.json](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/?view=aspnetcore-6.0#appsettingsjson) file).

The source object is inside an IQueryable, which is passed IMapper.ProjectTo().Because of this, based [on the AutoMapper documentation](https://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/Queryable-Extensions.html#supported-mapping-options), this limits my options to

- MapFrom (Expression-based)
- ConvertUsing (Expression-based)
- Ignore
- NullSubstitute
- Value transformers
- IncludeMembers

Disappointingly, I cannot use Custom Type Converters or Custom Resolvers.

So given these constraints, I have been trying to inject the settings using an [IOptions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/options?view=aspnetcore-6.0) as shown below.

```
public class DepartmentProfile : Profile
{
    private static IOptions<ApiOptions> _apiOptions;

    public DepartmentProfile(IOptions<ApiOptions> apiOptions)
    {
        _apiOptions = apiOptions;
    
        CreateMap<Media, MediaDto>()
           .ForMember(m => m.DepartmentTitle, o => o.MapFrom(src => src.Department.Title))
           .ForMember(m => m.DepartmentOption, o => o.MapFrom(src => GetOptionValue()))
    }

    private static string GetOptionValue()
    {
        return _apiOptions.Value.Option;
    }
}
```

The problem is I can't use this method since AutoMapper seems to want all mapping profile constructors to completely parameterless...

Furthermore, the code-base I'm working on has a very large number of mapping profiles that are all automatically registered using a single-line of code in the startup file- I don't really have the option of manually registering them at startup, and then passing extra options to them.

The code base is also architected in such a way that all the mapping logic really has to be done by the profile object itself- I cannot pass the object to another service after the automapper is done (for further mapping).

Does anyone know any way I can inject IOptions values to the mapping profile?

Comment: https://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Queryable-Extensions.html#parameterization

Comment: @LucianBargaoanu thank you for your feedback.  In the code, we register nearly 100 profiles in startup.cs with a single line of code that calls services.AddAutoMapper(assembly-name, Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly).  I need parameterization for a 1 specific profile only.  Can I register it without having to replace this startup functionality?  If so, how?

Comment: That's not relevant. The link explains how and there are many examples available online.

Comment: @LucianBargaoanu I appreciate your feedback, however I don't see how I can use the example in the link; in the example, the cfg object is used...I don't have access to the cfg object on which I can call the CreateProjection() method; not even in Startup.cs because startup.cs just registers everything with a single call to services.AddAutoMapper().  I don't see where I can register/create a projection.  Can you possibly specify where exactly I can register it?

Comment: Assembly scanning doesn't allow injecting services in profiles. But you can resolve the profile instances through the DI engine and add them in `AddAutoMapper`. Many people did this before, one way or another.

Comment: @LucianBargaoanu thank you again.  Can I just trouble you to provide a link to such an example?  I am relatively new .NET so am in need of guidance

Comment: @LucianBargaoanu also if I use your suggestion above, does that mean I cannot use assembly scanning?  There are about 100 profiles, so I would rather not register them manually in startup.cs

Comment: Actually you can, because you don't really need DI in your profile to pass parameters to `ProjecTo`, as my initial link shows.

Comment: @LucianBargaoanu the problem is I have nowhere to access the MapperConfiguration object.  Because my app uses assembly scanning, there is no opportunity in my code to write something ike var configuration = new MapperConfiguration(cfg => cfg.CreateProjection...>.  There is only one line in startup.cs for auto mapper and it is: return services.AddAutoMapper(Assembly.Load("AssemblyName"), Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());  I have no way to invoke the CreateProjection method to register any projection.  Do you know of any way I can register this projection while maintaining the assembly scanning?

Comment: @LucianBargaoanu, I have made progress; I had to first update to Automapper 11.0.0.  Now I am able to declare my CreateProjection within the DepartmentProfile.cs.  Tho that class, I have added a null string member, and then at runtime, I pass an anonymous object containing the value it must have.  Now my problem is that this parameter is being ignored, i.e. the member is still null after the projection.  Any ideas?

Comment: https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/blob/9ccbd7cad61f3b5901ad02f4355374582c46ba4f/src/IntegrationTests/ParameterizedQueries.cs#L54

Comment: @LucianBargaoanu thank you again for your feedback.  I currently have separate Profile classes in their own individual files.  Currently I have a working solution, but the projection is being registered in the startup file- do you know if it's possible for me to define the projection in a separate profile class (in its own .cs file) and have it get registered by assembly scanning?  I would rather avoid clogging up my startup.cs file projection definitions

Comment: You can define the maps anywhere as long as you pass the profile's type or assembly to `AddAutoMapper`.

Comment: @LucianBargaoanu if the assembly/type is passed to Automapper by autoscanning, will the parameterization still work?  Currently, when I use autoscanning (and define the projection on one of the scanned profiles) the parameter is ignored (kept null).  It only works if I create the projection inside the AddAutoMapper method call, in the startup file).

Comment: @LucianBargaoanu, I have been able to reach a solution, just wanted to thank you again for your help.  You contribution here is very useful.

Comment: You're welcome :)

Answer (score -1):

Alternative approach is to create a method with the argument for default value.

```
public MediaDto ToDto(this Media entity, string defaultOption)
{
    return new MediaDto 
    {
        DepartmentTitle = entity.DepartmentTitle,
        DepartmentOption = defaultOption
    };
}
```

Notice that you should be able to use this method in top level projections of IQueryable.

```
var items = query.Where(id => id == givenId)
    .Select(entity => ToDto(entity, option.Value))
    .ToList();
```

Benefits:

- Comprehensible for other developers
- Support any kind of mapping !!!important ;)
- No dependencies on third party frameworks